# save plot into image file in matlab: difference between saveas and print

Tags: image, matlab, printing, save-as

I wonder when saving plot into image file in matlab, what is the difference between saveas and print? In what cases both can be used and in what cases only one can be used?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe SAVEAS is just a wrapper for PRINT. Look at the source code for SAVEAS (edit saveas) - a lot of argument checks and only one print line at the end. Both function supports the same formats. SAVEAS has a little easier syntax.

From the SAVEAS remarks: `"If you want to control the size or resolution of figures saved in image (bitmapped) formats (such as BMP or JPG), use the print command."`

Answer (score 2):

Print is a lot more flexible in other ways as well. Look at the doc page for print - you can copy to the clipboard (e.g. with "print -dmeta") as well as, of course, printing to a printer.

Answer (score 0):

use hgexport instead, as follows:

```
hgexport(gcf, 'figure1.jpg', hgexport('factorystyle'), 'Format', 'jpeg');
```

source:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1PT49C/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-1PT49C