# MATLAB - How to avoid a jagged image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How do I avoid a jagged image in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)?

I have a 600 x 600 pixels image opened in MATLAB and do some processing on the image. However, when I save it, it looks so blurred and jagged. What should I do?

(This question is related to my previous question, *[MATLAB - How to plot x,y on an image and save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178336)*)

```
fid = fopen(datafile.txt);
A = textscan(fid,'%f%f%f'); %read data from the file
code = A{1};
xfix = A{2};
yfix = A{3};

for k=1:length(code)
    imagefile=code(k);
    rgb = imread([num2str(imagefile) '.jpg']);
    imshow(rgb);
    hold on;
    x = xfix2(k);
    y = yfix2(k);
    plot(x,y,'-+ b'); % plot x,y on the
    saveas(([num2str(imagefile) '.jpg'])) % Save the image with the same name as it open.
end
hold off
```

Comment: @Jessy can you post a code snippet?

Comment: @Vitor, I attached herewith the link of the code.

Comment: Are you using imwrite or imsave to save the image? What options are given to imwrite?

Comment: I used saveas - (([num2str(imagefile) '.jpg']))

Comment: @Jessy: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487692/save-plot-into-image-file-in-matlab-difference-between-saveas-and-print

Comment: @rwong - but the image turn to be blur.

Comment: when I look on the file that I saved from that code, the size and resolution of the image changed. How to maintain the size and pixel?

Comment: To make it not blur, either save as svg (a vector image format) or use a large size and high resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a resolution issue, perhaps using the print command (as listed below) with an explicit resolution option may fix it.

```
print(gcf,'-djpeg','-r600',[num2str(imagefile)])
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be JPEG compression artifacts. JPEG isn't a great format for data with a lot of high frequency components. Have you tried turning the compression down? Like so:

```
imwrite(f.cdata,([num2str(imagefile) '.jpg']),'Quality',100);
```

The default for the quality parameter is only 75. That's plenty for a lot of cases, but you might need more.

Comment: thanks the image are more clear now :) ...but the "+" which I used to plot the xy coordinate, which I set in blue color, turn into black color when I saved it. Why?